# yii2 update form pre-selected dropdown options based on model

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a post form where I create a a blog post within each one is a list of categories using a drop dropdown list populated with records from my categories table. When I select and submit the form it populates a join tables called CategoriesReviews containing the post id and the category id.

**Question**

How can I create my update form with the same dropdown list but with the categories that had been selected pre selected with in the list?

**View**

```
    <?= $form->field($categories, 'categories_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Categories::find()->all(), 'id', 'title'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select...', 'multiple' => true]);
    ?>
```

**Controller**

```
foreach ($_POST['CategoriesReviews']['categories_id'] as $category){
    $category = new CategoriesReviews();
    $category->post_id = $model->id;
    $category->category_id = $category; 
    $category->save(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `yii\widgets\ActiveField`, that means field's value is synchronized with model value. You simply need to fill `category_id` property with actual value on update (in your case array of existing assigned categories) and they will be preselected automatically.

Next thing, you are saving data wrong.

First of all, you should use `\Yii::$app->request->post()` abstraction instead. Next, `$_POST['CategoriesReviews']['categories_id']` needs to be checked for existence, with `isset` at least.

But that's not how you handle model data load and save. And junction table data is handled differently. You need to define relation and use `link()` method, for example:

```
$order->link('items', $item);
```

More info and examples are available in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations).

This is out of the box way of doing this, alternatively you can use some extensions for simplifying work with many-to-many:

- [arogachev/yii2-many-to-many](https://github.com/arogachev/yii2-many-to-many)
- [voskobovich/ManyToManyBehavior](https://github.com/voskobovich/ManyToManyBehavior)
- [yii2tech/ar-linkmany](https://github.com/yii2tech/ar-linkmany)